# I have a coding error, it says Echo is OFF when I try to run my .bat file

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have recently began coding and I am getting fairly well at it. But I have run into a mistake that I don't seem to know how to fix. Can anyone help? The code is-

```
color 0a
@echo off
echo (Name Later) Activating
echo Wscript.Sleep 5000>C:sleep5000.vbs
echo Wscript.Sleep 3000>C:sleep3000.vbs
echo Wscript.Sleep 4000>C:sleep4000.vbs
echo Wscript.Sleep 2000>C:sleep2000.vbs
start /w wscript C:sleep2000.vbs
echo Testing
start /w wscript C:sleep2000.vbs
echo Troll
start /w wscript C:sleep2000.vbs

:A
cd C://ProgramFiles(86x)/Google/Chrome/Application
start chrome.exe
start www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-    8#q=Halp+me+I+am+gunna+die
start /w wscript C:sleep4000.vbs
```

Is there an error I have made? Please let me know when you get the chance!

Comment: Comment all lines except the first out using `REM` or `::`. Run the batch file. If it runs without the error, you know that line is OK. Edit and remove the comment (`REM` or `::`) from the second line. Run it again. Rinse and repeat until you find the problem line, and then you can ask a question about why that line doesn't work. This is basic troubleshooting, which (if you're *getting fairly well at it*) you should know.

Comment: Also, the path separator in WIndows is the backslash, not the forward slash, and there is no such folder as `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)` on your computer. Start by fixing the obvious typos and omissions.

Comment: Does the statement `echo Troll` tell us something? path names containing spaces have to be enclosed in double quotes. Same applies  to URLs, especially when containing symbols with shouds be escaped `&|<>`

Comment: Ken, first off, thanks for the response! I understand it might be a easy troubleshoot but like I mentioned "I have recently began coding" and yes, I  am getting fairly well at it but I don't know all of the troubleshooting processes so excuse me for asking. LotPings, no, 'echo Troll' means nothing, I have nothing to write on that line yet, so it has no meaning. Thank you for the advice though!

Comment: Also, actually yes there is a file on my computer named C:\ProgramFiles(x86), yet the words are not together.

Comment: so `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)` isn't there (and shouldn't be there), but `C:\Program Files (x86)` is. This means, `cd C:\ProgramFiles(x86)` will fail. Another troubleshooting tip: run your script with `echo on` to see all executed commands and their response on the screen. Analyze the executed commands and watch out for any errormessages.

Comment: Thanks, Stephan, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write vbscript to have a sleep command, if you use the timeout command:

```bat
@Echo Off
Color 0A
Set CP="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Set WS=www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant
Set WS="%WS%&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Halp+me+I+am+gunna+die"
Echo (Name Later) Activating
Timeout/T 2 >Nul
Echo Testing
Timeout/T 2 >Nul
Echo Troll
Timeout/T 2 >Nul

:A
Start "" %CP% %WS%
Timeout/T 4 /NoBreak>Nul
```

Comment: Thank you, Compo, this resolved my problem completely!